# thenComparing vs sort

Tags: java-8, comparable

Are there any differences (e.g. performance, ordering) of the two versions:

version 1:

```
mylist.sort(myComparator.sort_item);
mylist.sort(myComparator.sort_post);
```

version 2:

```
// java 8
mylist.sort(myComparator.sort_item
            .thenComparing(myComparator.sort_post));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Java 8 API documentation:

> [thenComparing] Returns a lexicographic-order comparator with another
>   comparator. If this Comparator considers two elements equal, i.e.
>   compare(a, b) == 0, other is used to determine the order.

That means the second comparator is only used if the first one returns 0 (the elements are equal). So in practice it should be faster in most cases then calling sort twice.

In theory, if the sorting algorithm is of time complexity `C`, then calling it twice will still be `C` (constant multiplication doesn't matter) to the complexity of both sorting methods is the same.

Comment: So it means, both versions return equal results?

Comment: No, they do not.

Comment: @nimo23 They almost are. According to Java 8, the `List` interface now has a default method `sort` which is stable. That means that if you sort first by `sort_post` and then sort again by `sort_item`, the results are identical to sorting with the chained comparators in version 2. Note the reversed order in the version 1.

Comment: So I have to use mylist.sort(myComparator.sort_post
            .thenComparing(myComparator.sort_item));, if I want to sort like version 1.

Comment: Yes. But don't take my word for it, give it a shot, see what happens.

Answer (score 5):

Version 1: You are sorting by `item`, then throwing that sort away to sort by `post` instead.  Effectively, the first sort is meaningless.

Version 2: You are sorting first by `item`, and in the event of a tie, breaking that tie using `post`.

Comment: I dont understand what you mean by "meaningless". the objects of mylist have two properties "item" and "post" and I want to sort mylist at first with the "item-comparator" and after that, it should be sorted by "post"-comparator.

Comment: Assuming that, by "after that" you mean to break a tie, Version 1 will not do this.

Comment: @nimo23 I can't tell why *this* is not the accepted answer - this explains perfectly what is going on regarding your question.

Comment: When I sort with version 1, the list is sorted by the first comparator. When the second comparator sorts the pre-sorted list (coming from the first comparator), then the items will be sorted with regard of the pre-sorted list. If I dont use "sort_item" and only use "sort_post", the result is different, because "sort_item" was not made. But I need the sort of both comparator with the higher prioritiy of "sort_post" (hence, coming after the first comparator). So in short: The first sort is not meaningless, because the sort of both will be done (first ascending of item, second ascending of post).

Comment: The reason I say that the first sort is meaningless is because there is no guarantee that the `sort` method is a stable sort.  It may be that the default implementation is indeed stable.  But that is not guaranteed.

Comment: I can only accept one answer. Sorry. However, both anwers are right. Thanks.

Comment: @JoeC: that’s a specification flaw. The documentation of `Collections.sort` states that it is guaranteed to be stable, but merely delegates to `List.sort` in recent versions, obviously expecting it to be stable, despite the documentation of `List.sort` is less clear about it.